# Do I need mongodb or mysql for my web-application?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, solr, elasticsearch

I am a newbie with balls :) I am developing a web-application with huge potential (at least in the GB sense of the word). Think bookmarks (like diigo). I want to store bookmarks, with url, title, description, tags and also the actual html-content at the time of bookmarking. And I want it all to be searchable.

What database fits my needs the best? I have been reading about mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, mysql and other sql-variants, but I cannot figure out what is best for me.

To tell you what I need (everything in the context of one specific user), I need:

- Search in url, title and tags (I guess any db would do a fine job there?)
- General search (meaning the above + the html-file stored of the actual site)

In addition I need:

- General search for anything (user, date. url, title, tags, html-pages and so on)

When my service is small, then all options are probably ok, but what if I suddenly find myself in a explosive expansion of users, what then?

---

**Edit:**
I was blown away with [Algolia](http://www.algolia.com/)! Incredible for text searches! And fast! See [this](http://blog.algolia.com/full-text-search-in-your-database-algolia-versus-elasticsearch/) comparison with Elasticsearch.

Comment: 1. You should not use edits to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  2. It's still off-topic.

Comment: Learning something new every day. I thought since I cannot delete the question, and since I cannot turn it on-topic, I might as well tip future readers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Premature optimization is the root of all evil
2. If you or your team has experience with one RDBMS over another, go with what you already know.
3. Postgres more than holds it on in the no-sql arena: http://thebuild.com/presentations/pg-as-nosql-pgday-fosdem-2013.pdf
4. Postgres full text indexes rock: http://blog.lostpropertyhq.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/
5. I don't have much experience with postgres scaling, but there are a lot of success stories: https://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/scaling-postgresql-at-braintree-four-years-of-evolution

Comment: Well, my post is put "on hold", so I guess I will not get any other answers. I will accept this one based primarily on point 1 and 2. Phrased differently: Use whatever you know and if you are successful then do optimization. I can buy that :) Takker @Andreas